# AJAX data not passed to php correctly only in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, post

I have js file which is calling a php file. following is the code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user.php",   
        data: {username : username.val(),password : password.val()},
    success: function(result) {                     
        if (result==0)
        {  
            //displayerror;
        }
        else
        {
             location.reload(true);
        }
    }
});
```

in user.php file I'm assign variables as follows,

```
$username =$_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
```

When browsing using Internet Explorer 11 it is giving an error "Notice Undefined index username".

When I check POST values in php file using

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

it is returning array(0){}. I also checked js file's passing data object. It contains correct values as expected.

Above code is working fine in Firefox as well as in the Chrome.

Does any one have an idea what's wrong in IE?

Thank you

Comment: thanks for your response. it's jquery-1.9.1.js.

Comment: make sure to grab the latest 1.x jquery as they have just fixed some IE11 related $.ajax problem.

Comment: I tried with jquery-1.10.2.js. still no luck.

Comment: Try 1.11.0-beta2: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0-beta2.js

Comment: how do you start the ajax call? onclick or onload or something else?

Comment: hi bagonyi, have same error with jquery-1.11.0-beta2.js.

Comment: hi lgoel, Im calling this on button click. $("#login" ).button().click(function() {...